# Android-Studio shuts down every time I try to open a xml file. (CODE and Design)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

This is my first post here. I'm having an issue using Android-Studio. Everytime I try to open a xml file, it simply shuts down, no error log or message. I tried tons of possibly solutions, but none worked. I'm using the last version,run invalidate and restart, clean project, create a new xml file, and it keeps shuting down. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: how about just reinstalling android studio maybe something happened to some files :\

Comment: Which version of AS and on which OS? And is it 1 particular xml file or any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is over ram usage bug on layout editor with android studio stable release. I recommend you to use [Android Studio Canary 12 Bumblebee](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview?gclid=CjwKCAjw4qCKBhAVEiwAkTYsPC7_0uYyR9mqPJWI6IlVBDxnobj3PRHRzrG1YUvkxfxbjuxJKbj_9xoCksoQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) (Preview build) until stable release bug fixed.

Comment: Thank you man! It did work well! Now I can get back to normal life! haha...

Comment: Not at all.. Yeah I lived that life for a while too..